# LinkedIn API - get ID of posted comment

Tags: api, linkedin-api

As no one answers in the LinkedIn Dev Forum - perhaps anyone here can help. :-/

When posting a status update you get the corresponding update-key within the response.
But when posting a **comment** over

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key={NETWORK UPDATE KEY}/update-comments
```

the response string "linkedin" is empty and I can't see any key or id of the comment, I've successfully(!) posted.

And I'm in need of this **comment id**.

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: Nope. The LinkedIn support is horrible. Didn't get any helpful answer. Had to make a (not nice) workaraound.

Comment: Hello , Same problem. , year 2018, same problem